# Rook-Ceph Deployment: Error when creating csi-cephfsplugin-provisioner and csi-rdb-plugin-provisioner

Tags: raspberry-pi, k3s

I have an issue with setting up rook ceph cluster on raspberry pis. Since there is no official arm support I am using the raspbernetes images like the guide [rook on arm](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-develop-for-arm-on-a-budget-bfc433bdad07), I hope I am in the right place to ask for guidance. Similar guides like [G1](https://blog.codegiant.io/how-to-deploy-a-ceph-cluster-on-kubernetes-with-rook-daf24e6db914) and [G2](https://medium.com/@fdeantoni/running-rook-with-k3s-5e2c79159eaf) are doing the same thing basically, but without the arm considerations.

`ROOK_CSI_CEPH_IMAGE: "raspbernetes/ceph-csi:v3.1.0" ROOK_CSI_REGISTRAR_IMAGE: "raspbernetes/csi-node-driver-registrar:1.3.0" ROOK_CSI_RESIZER_IMAGE: "raspbernetes/csi-external-resizer:0.5.0" ROOK_CSI_PROVISIONER_IMAGE: "raspbernetes/csi-external-provisioner:1.6.0" ROOK_CSI_SNAPSHOTTER_IMAGE: "raspbernetes/csi-external-snapshotter:2.1.1" ROOK_CSI_ATTACHER_IMAGE: "raspbernetes/csi-external-attacher:2.2.0"`

When applying the default/example cluster.yaml i have a similar error in the cephfs and rdb provisioners.

`error: a container name must be specified for pod csi-cephfsplugin-provisioner-5cb7799c98-dp5tx, choose one of: [csi-attacher csi-snapshotter csi-resizer csi-provisioner csi-cephfsplugin liveness-prometheus]`

**Deviation from expected behavior:**
If I understand the error message correctly I have a missing definition in one of the examples .yamls, but I can't find out what I have to change exactly. The error also shows that it is not an architectural problem I think.

EDIT: according to this post [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129376/kubernetes-kubectl-a-container-name-must-be-specified-but-seems-like-it-is), this error occurs when the pod of the container can be found among many. So I guess that I have to point the provisioner container to the applicable pods. But how?

**Expected behavior:**
Simple deployment into the running status of cephfs and rdb provisioner.

**How to reproduce it (minimal and precise):**
3 or 6 raspberry pies with m.2 SATA SSDs and adapters, running ubuntu64 for arm. k3s kubernetes HA setup with external etcd cluster and multiple services running fine. Integration of rook-ceph via the guide [rook on arm](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-develop-for-arm-on-a-budget-bfc433bdad07).

**Environment**:

- OS: Ubuntu64 focal for arm
- Kernel: Linux server-01 5.4.0-1025-raspi #28-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 9 17:10:53 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
- Cloud provider or hardware configuration: RaspberryPi4 8gb
- Rook version: master and rook/ceph:v1.5.4
- Storage backend version: ceph/ceph:v15.2.8
- Kubernetes version: v1.19.5+k3s2
- Kubernetes cluster type: k3s

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Is there any update on this.